# $(document).ready() || setTimeout?

Tags: jquery

I have code (not necessary for the question) which needs to be executed after $(document).ready() **or** if the window is loaded for let's say 5 seconds.

I tried to figure it out, but I couldn't find anything on the web. Hope someone here can help me!

(I know how to do it separate like in 2 statements, but I need to put it in a OR statement.)

Edit: To make it more clear for people. Either **wait** till the document is ready aka dom is builded **OR** if after 5 seconds the document still isn't ready BUT the window is loaded, just execute the function.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why is on *either* on DOM ready or after five seconds?

Comment: `setTimeout` is not an option?

Comment: *"if the window is loaded"* - The window? Do you mean the document? Five seconds after the document is loaded will be *after* the document ready event, so your requirement doesn't make sense. Or do you mean five seconds after the page first begins to load?

Comment: Afaik window loaded is when the window, browser window, is loaded. Document ready is when the DOM is builded :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to schedule the operation, then put `clearTimeout` in `$(document).ready()` to cancel it if the document becomes ready sooner.

And use a variable to tell if the function has already been run by the timer, so you don't do it again in the ready function.

```
var functionDone = false;
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    someFunction();
    functionDone = true;
}, 5000);
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!functionDone) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        someFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a resuable solution, you can create a generate timeout wrapper like this:

```
// return a new function to pass to document.ready
// that has a timeout wrapper on it
function timeoutFn(fn, t) {
    var fired = false;
    var timer;
    function run() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        if (!fired) {
            fired = true;
            fn();
        }
    }
    timer = setTimeout(run, t);
    return run;
}
```

And, then use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(timeoutFn(function() {
    // put code here for function that will be called
    // at the earlier occurrence of 5 seconds or document.ready
}, 5000));
```

---

Or, you could make this a jQuery plug-in:

```
jQuery.fn.readyTimeout = function(fn, t) {
    return $(document).ready(timeoutFn(fn, t));
}
```

And, use it like this:

```
$(document).readyTimeout(function() {
    // put code here for function that will be called
    // at the earlier occurrence of 5 seconds or document.ready
}, 5000);
```