# Promisify event handlers and timeout in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, event-handling, promise

I have a callback handler to handle a websocket event and I am trying to write a function which would return a promise. The promise should be resolved if the handler is called or rejected if the handler is not executed. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var callbackCalled = false;
var message = null;

waitForMessage = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (callbackCalled) {
        callbackCalled = false;
        message = null;
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }, 5000);
  });
}

onEvent = function(event) {
  console.log("Process the event");
  //set the message
  callbackCalled = true;
};
```

Comment: I think you can use the `timeoutFn()` function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325035/document-ready-settimeout/40325092#40325092.

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like this.  This will reject is the timeout happens before the incoming event.  It will resolve with data if the event happens before the timeout.

```
function waitForEventWithTimeout(socket, event, t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var timer;

        function listener(data) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            socket.removeListener(event, listener);
            resolve(data);
        }

        socket.on(event, listener);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            socket.removeListener(event, listener);
            reject(new Error("timeout"));
        }, t);
    });
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
waitForEventWithTimeout(socket, "myEvent", 1000).then(function(data) {
    // got data here
}, function() {
    // timeout here
});
```

Note, I add and remove the event listener here to make sure it's not processed too many times or added too many times because event handlers are multi-shot listeners, but promises are one shot.

Comment: @learningtocode - If this worked for you, then you can indicate to the community that your question has been answered by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.