# How do I make a Promise that resolves when an event emitter emits an event in JS or Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, events, promise

I want to make a Promise that resolves once an event emitter emits an event. I am using Node JS.

I think this may work, but how do I make the promise wait until the event happens.

```
function foo(resolve,reject){
    something.on("random",() => {
        resolve("good");
    });
}

let p = new Promise(foo);

p.then(() => {
    console.log("Event!!!");
});
```

Comment: Easiest solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-event or checkout this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352682/promisify-event-handlers-and-tiemout-in-nodejs

Comment: Thanks. This should do it.

Comment: "*how do I make the promise wait until the event happens.*" - you already do, the `console.log("Event!!!");` won't occur before the `random` event fires?!

Comment: Sorry that I asked, but I am new to Promises and I didn`t have enough time to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is about fine, apart from that you should use `once` instead of `on` so that the event handler is removed after the first occurrence of the event - the promise can be resolve only once anyway.

If you have node v11.13.0 or higher you can also use the [`events.once` method](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name) so that you don't have to build the promise yourself - and it also handles error events correctly:

```
import { once } from 'events';

const p = once(something, "random");

p.then(() => {
    console.log("Event good!");
});
```